# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.camel.Processor when deploying war to weblogic

Tags: java, apache, weblogic, war, oracle12c

Hi i try to deploy a war into weblogic 12c but i have the following error

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.camel.Processor when deploying war to weblogic
```

Here are the log traces :

```
weblogic.management.DeploymentException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.camel.Processor at weblogic.application.internal.BaseDeployment.throwAppException(BaseDeployment.java:132) at weblogic.application.internal.BaseDeployment.prepare(BaseDeployment.java:244) at weblogic.application.internal.SingleModuleDeployment.prepare(SingleModuleDeployment.java:52) at weblogic.application.internal.DeploymentStateChecker.prepare(DeploymentStateChecker.java:158) at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.AppContainerInvoker.prepare(AppContainerInvoker.java:65) Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace


Caused By: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.camel.Processor at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.findLocalClass(GenericClassLoader.java:1029) at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.findClass(GenericClassLoader.java:990) at weblogic.utils.classloaders.ChangeAwareClassLoader.findClass(ChangeAwareClassLoader.java:104) at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.doFindClass(GenericClassLoader.java:611) at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.loadClass(GenericClassLoader.java:543) Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
```

Thank's for your help :)

Comment: did you check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25665309/warning-when-deploying-apache-camel-application

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add jar dependencies to pom.xml. If your project is not in Maven, please download this jar and add your lib folder.

```
<dependency>
 <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
 <artifactId>camel-core</artifactId>
 <version>2.9.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: This is a library that i'm not using in my project. Should it be embedded with weblogic ?

Comment: yes, you can try.